How do I create a curved edge onto my cube?
I am trying to create a cube with extruding parts, and the edges of these extrusions should be curved on the inside, like in the image

Here is what I have modeled


Use the bevel operation (Ctrl B)? Also, do you need so many subdivisions?

I don't quite know how to use the bevel thingy in this case, I am quite new
And no, probably not but it works

You can select all and X > Limited Dissolve in order to simplify the topology, remove the front face, select these edges:

Bevel with CtrlB, in the Operator Box enable Clamp Overlap and increase the Width until it clamps:

Select all and press M > Merge by Distance to merge the overlapping vertices:

Select the edge loop with AltRMB to fill the front face again:

For your current object, once you've dissolved you can't avoid having some edge remaining, just correct the topology a bit, make sure that you don't have adjacent or overlapping vertices:

Then you'll be able to bevel correctly (no need to remove the face like in my screenshot), at the end don't forget to select all and M > Merge by Distance:


When I try to use limited dissolve, it always gets these little areas that wont dissolve, making the beveling not work properly

could you please share your file? read the instructions: https://blend-exchange.com/

I am not at home right now, but the way I do it is I take a cube, subdivide it a few times, extrude the edges, then try to use limited dissolve. The areas that do not dissolve arent consistent and dont always hinder the beveling, but it is regardless rather odd

I'm not sure what's happening, it should work, please share your file just before you're supposed to bevel

Alright, give me a second and I can send you a recreation of the file, I still don't have access to my home computer but I've been able to recreate the problem here
Side note, how do I attach a file to comments?

read the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.com/ or use a platform like workupload

Here is the file before dissolving, if I did this right


I've edited my answer, I hope it helps
